# Wordpress: User front-end upload saved to Wordpress directory

Tags: php, html, wordpress, file-upload

Is it possible for a user to upload a file in the front end which will be saved to a folder in my theme directory using PHP? The folder is wp-uploads which is within wp-content. How can the destination for the upload be specified? The code used for the front-end upload:

```
<input name="usp-files[]" type="file" maxlength="255" data-required="false" placeholder="File(s)" class="usp-input usp-input-files select-file multiple" multiple="multiple" id="usp-multiple-files" />
<input name="usp-file-limit" class="usp-file-limit" value="20" type="hidden" />
<input name="usp-file-count" class="usp-file-count" value="1" type="hidden" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set file save path what you need https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/upload_dir

And after this upload file from frontend https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_handle_upload